# Python selenium switch to window with specific URL

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a python code with selenium that opens multiple windows. I know how to switch between them numerically but is there a way to switch to a specific tab that’s already open by searching the URL?

Answer (score 0):

In Java `browser.switchWindow(urlOrTitleToMatch)` can do the trick, 
where  `urlOrTitleToMatch` is your URL string or a regular expression.
https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/switchWindow.html

### Edit

In Python it looks like you have to loop through all windows until you find a URL match.

```
import re

def switchWindow(URL, browser):
  for window in browser.getWindowHandles():
    browser.switch_to_window(window)
    if re.search(URL, browser.current_url):
      break;
```

Comment: @Spencer You're right. Looks like that's Java only. Will the Python function I posted work for you?